# Android Studio IBus daemon

Tags: 14.04, android, ibus, android-studio

how can I resolve that problem in Ubuntu 14.04 with Android Studio

```
Your system is using the IBus daemon which is known to cause intermittent 
keyboard issues with the IDE. See known issues for suggested workarounds.
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Keyboard issues with Android Studio on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756488/keyboard-issues-with-android-studio-on-ubuntu). If you're confused about the information provided, you just need to execute the commands indicated by **$** sign on a terminal. [http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus]

Answer (score 0):

If it's not messing up your typing in Android Studio, ignore it.  I have tried [workaround #1](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus), but it messed up my keyboard and mouse, so I turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu uses Ctrl+Alt+L for screen blocking, android studio - for automatic text format. i changed my ubuntu hotkey to win+L